# Anyone can edit?

Tags: support, editing

Surely I have missed something as I though editing questions or answers was allowed at 2000 rep?

Today, twice, a user with 1 rep edited my answer. I rejected it and so I don't have a link anymore, but here is a screen capture:

[image: suggested edit review]

Am I wrong about the needed reputation?

Comment: The user gets some rep for a suggested edit IIRC.  At 1 you need rep to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a [suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/278094), and yes anyone below 2000 rep (the edit privilege) can suggest an edit to any post.

Suggested edits differ from an edit, in that suggested edits must be reviewed.
For example if I edited that post, you would not even know. However with a suggested edit SE first pings the OP (you) and you get a link to the suggested edit review queue (here is the link to the [review](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/37445) in question)

So yes anybody can edit, but edits from users with less then 2000 rep have to clear the review before the post is actually edited.

Comment: OK, and thanks for the proof of concept...

Comment: sure :) What I do is every so often look at the [responses tab](http://blender.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses) in my profile that shows when one of your posts gets edited.